# Setting a static IP address in /etc/network/interfaces disables WiFi - Country Code not set

Tags: networking, wifi, static-ip

I want to assign a static IP-address to the Wireless LAN interface on my raspberry pi, but after setting the address in `/etc/network/interfaces`

as follows:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

and then after rebooting my raspberry pi, the WiFi is disabled with the message "country code not set".

But the country code is set in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` The third line is `country=BE`

When removing the wlan0 setting in `/etc/network/interfaces` and rebooting the raspberry pi, the Wi-Fi is enabled again. (but with a useless `169.254.0.0/16` ip-address)

Comment: Why do you think the file contains "# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
"? Why dou want to set a static IP-address in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspbian networking is not managed by `ifupdown` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Please don't ignore the hint in it:

> # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
>   # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

You should edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and set static entries in it. You will find examples there.

If you really want to manage your static ip address in `/etc/network/interfaces` then you should either exclude the interface from managing by `dhcpcd` or you disable `dhcpcd` complete. But then you have to do all other network stuff also by yourself.